# Shapefile of Portugal 4 digit Postal codes

Tags: geospatial, postal-code, portugal

I'm looking for shapefiles that contain Portugal 4 digits postal codes polygons

Are there any open-source or public resources where I can obtain these files?

Comment: openstreetmap.org might have this data, but I haven't had a chance to dig

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to it. Scroll down at the bottom on how to get the gis data.

https://worldpostalcode.com/portugal/

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I couldn't find any info on how to acquire the shapefiles after scrolling down. Could you kindly guide me?

Comment: Yes it is there. Like I said it is at the bottom of the site.  So here is the link http://www.geonames.org/

Comment: Thank you, but What I am looking for are shapefiles containing Portugal postal code areas.

Comment: I understand. I have look around but that link I gave you is the only link. If you really need it as a whole, my suggest to you is to contact the university in Portugal. Contact any Geography department and they may help you guide to find one. It might be a good one to find the latest current one.

Comment: Maybe I found it here https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata

Comment: Thank you for the link and for the tip. I could only find the point coordinates of the postcode in Portugal. Perhaps it's best that I try contacting the University of Portugal.

Comment: Yes I think you might want the polygons instead of the points. Wish you luck.

Comment: Well, I think I found the Postal Codes for Portugal. Problem is what software do you use ? ESRI has that on their ArcGIS Online. https://esri.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1a027dbc06b048c4a7c07a53371a95bc

Answer (score 0):

Is it something you are looking for? https://github.com/temospena/CP7