# Is there a database where I can find the postal codes of Portugal as polygons?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, postal-code, portugal

I am searching for a file where I can see Portugal's 7-digit postal codes as polygons.

Does anybody know of a database or a site where I can find information like that?

Comment: Perhaps you could generate Voronoi polygons from this dataset (points)? https://github.com/temospena/CP7

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Have a look at this [answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/20140/shapefile-of-portugal-4-digit-postal-codes). The data area available at [World PostCode](https://worldpostalcode.com/portugal/)